# How can I add a short-cut key to tmux conf that does more than one command?

Tags: scripting, tmux

How can I add short-cuts to tmux? -- like ctrl-h might first synchronize the panes then run hostname, then un-synchronize.  Also, by more elaborate I might want it to run a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your panes are shells you can use something like this to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind C-h
bind C-h setw synchronize-panes on \; send-keys hostname C-m \; setw synchronize-panes off \; send-keys ./script C-m
```